# How to diplay the boxplot in order with date x - axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

How can I make this in order of month, x axis is not in date class its in character? I tried using reorder and sort it doesn't work for my case.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches.

Fake data:

```r
set.seed(42) # R-4.0.2
dat <- data.frame(
  when = sample(c("Apr20", "Feb20", "Mar20"), size = 500, replace = TRUE),
  charge = 10000 * rexp(500)
)
ggplot(dat, aes(charge, when)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: basic plot, x-axis is in wrong order]

---

### `Date` class

This is what I'll call "The Right Way (tm)", for two reasons: if the data is date-like, them let's use `Date`; and allow R to handle the ordering *naturally*.

```r
dat$when2 <- as.Date(paste0("01", dat$when), "%d%b%y")
ggplot(dat, aes(charge, when2, group = when)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_date(labels = function(z) format(z, format = "%b%y"))
```

[image: same plot, x-axis ordered by Date class]

(I should note that I need both `when2` and `group=when`: since `when2` is a continuous variable, `ggplot2` is not going to auto-group things based on it, so we need `group=`.)

---

### `factor`

I think this is the wrong approach, for two reasons: (1) not using dates as the numeric data they are; and (2) the more months you have, the more you have to **manually** control the levels within the factors.

However, having said that:

```r
dat$when3 <- factor(dat$when, levels = c("Feb20", "Mar20", "Apr20"))
ggplot(dat, aes(charge, when3)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: same plot, ordered by factor, not Date]

(You could easily overwrite `dat$when` instead of creating a new variable `dat$when3`, but I kept it separate because I went back and forth during code-testing here. Frankly, if you prefer to *not* go the `Date` route, then doing this allows other things to be ordered correctly, too.)